# Application.Match on multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working macro that finds duplicates on a different worksheet and highlights them.

```
Sub dedup()

Dim i As Long
Dim x As Variant

With Worksheets(1)
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        x = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "C").Value, Worksheets(2).Columns("C"), 0)
        If Not IsError(x) Then
            .Cells(i, "C").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

I am trying to now filter the "duplicates" based on a criteria, that is, another column - Column A. The duplicates are to be considered duplicates only if even the Column A values match.

```
Sub dedup()

Dim i As Long
Dim x As Variant

With Worksheets(1)
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        x = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "C").Value & .Cells(i, "A").Value, Worksheets(2).Columns("C") & Worksheets(2).Columns("A"), 0)
        If Not IsError(x) Then
            .Cells(i, "C").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

The logic here, was to concatenate my query and the range I am querying. But, I get a "Type mismatch" error.

Column C is a numeric value, and Column A is a date value

Comment: You can't do `Worksheets(2).Columns("C") & Worksheets(2).Columns("A")` in VBA. You could potentially use `Evaluate` here. Or probably better, `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate multicell ranges like `Worksheets(2).Columns("C") & Worksheets(2).Columns("A")`. Remember this is vba - not python :). You can, however do it within excel as in an array formula so you can use something like

```
Dim sShtName as String: sShtName = Sheets(2).name

Evaluate("=MATCH(""" & .Cells(i, "C").Value & .Cells(i, "A").Value & """," & sShtName & "!C:C&" & sShtName & "!A:A,0)")
```

Don't expect this to be fast. You can build a loop to test a match. You can also add a column in `Sheets(2)` that will hold the concatenated values and `Match` in this column.

**Edit**

A much better approach (as suggested by @BigBen) is the use of `Application.CountIfs` function. The reason it is better (@BigBen can comment on this) is that you do not have to check for errors and all you want is to check whether the value exists or not (i.e. you don't care about where that value is)

Comment: What is your rationale for using `WorksheetFunction.Match` instead of `Application.Match`?

Comment: @BigBen Didn't even know that `Application.Match` existed :) You can't say anything to that, can you? :D

Comment: I simply tested with the VBE and it didn't autocomplete so I assumed it didn't exist: edited my answer

Comment: It's just the late-bound form of `WorksheetFunction.Match`. So yes, intellisense will not work when you type it. Note that you then need to use `IsError`, as OP is already doing.

Comment: @BigBen So does that mean it is a little faster to use `WorksheetFunction.Match`? If so, then I want to change my rantioanle to this (sounds much better)

Comment: I find `Application.Match` to be much easier to use. To be honest though, I think OP can just use `CountIfs`, as either `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` or `Application.CountIfs`, and test if the result is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hi see if following code answers your expectations. I have tweaked it a little bit as per what I could read from your question.

```
Sub dedup()

Dim i As Long
Dim x, y As Variant

    With Worksheets(1)
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            
                x = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A").Value, Worksheets(2).Columns("A"), 0)
                y = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "C").Value, Worksheets(2).Columns("C"), 0)
                
                If Not IsError(x) Or IsError(y) Then
                    .Cells(i, "C").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                End If
            
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```